# How to use localstorage in multiple async await?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, local-storage

I'm making multiple calls on an endpoint to get the image of a blob and I need to save it in localstorage so that if it exists there, it's not necessary to make the call again.

The way I'm doing it, it's not waiting for the keys to spread the setItem array.

What is the correct way to do this?

```
   assetNameFiltered.forEach((assetName) => {
      const ASSET_IMAGE = assetImageCached?.filter(({ id }) => id === assetName)[0];

      if (ASSET_IMAGE) {
        //
      } else {
        useOperationServiceHook.getAssetImageByName(assetName).then(({ data }) => {
          if (data.size > 0) {
            const READER = new window.FileReader();
            READER.readAsDataURL(data);
            READER.onloadend = () => createAssetImageCache({ id: assetName, image: READER.result });
          } else {
            createAssetImageCache({ id: assetName, image: '' });
          }
        });
      }
    });
```

Comment: did you post the wrong code? none of that code uses async/await or `localStorage`

Comment: I'm using then, it's a promise.

Comment: sure, so to use async/await you can `const { data } = await useOperationServiceHook.getAssetImageByName(assetName)` - but, async/await in `.forEach` rarely works like you want it it work

Comment: How can I create an array of dynamic objects and set it in localstorage and then get the cached data?

Comment: not sure what "dynamic objects" you want in an array, but since localStorage obly works with strings, you'll want to JSON.stringify this array when storing it and JSON.parse it when you read it from localStorage - since your code doesn't even attempt such things it's hard to know exactly what you want stored in localStorage

Comment: Yes, I already tried that, the problem is that when you do this within multiple calls to the backend, even pushing the array outside and giving setItem it only inserts one item.

Comment: *I already tried that* - not in the code you've shown - you need to show what you've tried, that way, we can see what you want to do, and explain how you're doing it wrong